# Suppose $f$ is a monotonic function such that $f(x)e^{f(x)} = x$. Find the value of $\int_0^e f$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, inverse-function

I have a function $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that :

- $f(x)e^{f(x)} = x$ for all $x \geq 0$.
- $f$ is monotonic.
- $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty $.

  Then, I have to evaluate :
  $$(1). \quad \int_0^e f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
  $$(2). \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\ln x}$$

  Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean the principal branch of the [Lambert-W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) - $W_0$?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Define a function $g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ by the rule $$g(x)=xe^x$$
Now, you may to check that $g$ is non-decreasing over its entire domain (ckeck the sign of its derivative) and hence $g$ has an inverse. By the hypotheses of the problem we can conclude that $f$ is its inverse.

To solve $(1)$ substitute $u=f(x)$. Then $x=g(u)=ue^u$ and $dx=\dots$

Can you continue from here?

*Note :* $x=0$ iff $u=0$ and $x=e$ iff $u=1$.

Answer (score 0):

With $w:=f(x)$, the integral is $\int_0^1(w+w^2)e^wdw=[(1-w+w^2)e^w]_0^1=e-1$, while the limit is $\lim_{w\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\ln w}{w}}=\frac{1}{1+0}=1$.